# Domain Name Service (DNS) A/ASN/NSrecords of Fast-Flux Domains

Tags: data-request

I am looking for DNS Resource Records of Fast-Flux networks. I have been searching for a while now and I did find some torrents but I am not allowed to download torrents from my work. This is the link I found:
https://www.reddit.com/r/netsec/comments/1t6nz8/dns_census_2013_dataset_containing_2676380336_dns/